# AMQP 1.0 topic non-durable consumer

Tags: java, messaging, amqp, jms-topic, cloudamqp

For some time now I'm trying to create topic consumer that will not require subscription.
So i would like to achieve similar behavior like with JMS non-durable topic subscriber.

I'm using MS Azure AMQP 1.0 service bus and apache qpid amqp 1.0 client (JMS implementation).

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you described what you had already tried and what exactly did not work for you (any code samples would be good as well). While I am not an expert on the topic it seems a little bit unclear to me what help you actually need.